# How to create anchor on django admin page to scroll down to an inline or field automatically from a url

Tags: html, django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I have a fairly big model and on the admin page for that model I have a few inlines that show up at the bottom. I want to be able to link to the admin page for a model instance, and automatically scroll down to an inline so something like /admin/myapp/modelname/pk/#inlinename

I'm not even remotely sure where to start? 
If anyone can even point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for an animated scroll effect? Or do you just want to jump to the anchor tag with the id?

Comment: I just want to jump to the anchor tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every inline has an id in the form of `[related_name]-group`. If you didn't specify a `related_name` on the relationship then the default related name would be in the form of `[lowercase model name]_set`.

So, let's say you had a relationship to model, `Foo`, with no `related_name` specified. The inline's id would be `#foo_set-group`, which you can link to as anchor.

Comment: it seems to work for one of my inlines, but it's because that model is  a many2many field on the parent model, whereas the other 2 inlines are separate models that are not referenced in that parent model, but have a foreign key to it.

Comment: blah so on the m2m field, it doesn't work with the related name, but it works with #modelname_set-group and on the other inlines whose models reference the parent model with a fkey, it works if i set a related name, but doesnt work otherwise... weird

thanks for the help I got it working but like I pointed above it's kind of weird